# Spinner não aparece texto dentro dele

Tags: android

A seta do spinner aparece mas o texto não e mesmo quando escolho uma das opções do spinner nada acontece aparece vazio sem  a opção escolhida...a versão mínima no meu grandle é a versão 11 máxima é 24.

**O meu xml:**

```
 <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerlinha"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvlinhas"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#ff0000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                   />
```

**O meu código :**

```
      linhaSP=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerlinha);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                linhaNome);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
linhaSP.setAdapter(adapter);

        linhaSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                       View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Onde está o código para preencher o array `linhaNome`?

Comment: Ver por json mas está me a dar as opções correctas no momento do click nada acontece

Answer (score 1):

O problema está em `android:background="#000"` que atribui a cor preta ao *background*.

Como `android:textColor="#ff0000"` não tem efeito algum(não altera a cor do texto para vermelho).

O resultado é texto preto em fundo preto.

Remova esses dois atributos, ou coloque outra cor para o fundo.

Se quiser mudar a cor do texto e do fundo faça o seguinte:

Na pasta *layout* crie o arquivo **spinner_item.xml** com este código:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Altere as cores ao seu gosto.
Instancie o *adapter* desta forma:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item,
            linhaNome);
```

Se quiser que a *Dropdown view* tenha cores diferentes, crie um novo arquivo chamado **spinner_dropdown_item.xml** com o mesmo código do anterior mas com essas outras cores.

No java, a seguir a instanciar o *adapter*, coloque:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: O erro continua a existir veja a modificação da minha pergunta , o fundo não aparece a verde como era suposto e nem aparece texto

Comment: Eu testei e tudo funciona como esperado.

Comment: Pode ser da minha versão do dispositivo onde estou a usar a apk ?

Comment: Julgo que não. Você tem algum *custom style*? Não devia ter editado a pergunta, a minha resposta agora ficou sem sentido. Devia reverter a edição.